# Fatal error when compiling Qt in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt5

I tried to build Qt 5.0.1 with MSVS2010 in Windows 7.

These are my steps:

1. Extract source code into C:\Qt\5.0.1
2. Start VS2010 command prompt
3. Type configure (this step took approximately 45 minute)
4. Type nmake

After an hour I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDKUtilities\bin\x86\fxc.exe"
/nologo /E standardvs /T vs_2_0 /Fh shaders\standardvs.h ..\..\..\3rdparty\angle
\src\libGLESv2\shaders\Blit.vs

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDKUtiliti
es\bin\x86\fxc.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Stop.
```

I searched online, and saw many solutions, but none of them solved my problem.
I even re-installed Windows and repeated those steps but I got the same error again.

Comment: which path was it that you needed to change? I have exactly the same problem in Windows 8 with VS2013...

Comment: ...and changed all environment variables to not contain spaces anymore, ran configure again, but didn't help :(

Comment: For me, I needed to install the Microsoft SDK. The actual compiler was missing. By running "cl.exe" I found it was not present. After installation the compiler commands were automatically added to the environment path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have spaces and parenthesis in your env paths. Try to use short path, you can get them by opening a Windows command prompt with `cmd` and type `dir /X`. Short names will be in front of corresponding directories

for example, if you have a script to set up your environment :

```
SET VISUALDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
SET PATH=%VISUALDIR%\VC\bin;%PATH%
```

becomes

```
SET VISUALDIR=C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1.0
SET PATH=%VISUALDIR%\VC\bin;%PATH%
```

If you have no script, the faulty path could be set in the default Windows `PATH` environment variable. Then you'll have to manually edit `PATH` variable and apply short paths here.

windows power

Comment: For anyone else that comes along... For me, this was a problem with spaces in the path names within the $LIB and $INCLUDE environment variables. I build under cygwin, but the same issue probably applies in the pure Windows environment too. This response helped clue me into the problem, since the message is M$-cryptic.