# Building Qt - NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, nmake

I'm trying to build Qt5.5 with static linking using msvc2015 but I'm having the following errors (actually there's a whole lot of them but I'm only listing a few, they're all quite the same):

```
K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdint(50): error C2873: 'uint_fast64_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdint(52): error C2039: 'intmax_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''
K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdint(52): error C2873: 'intmax_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdint(53): error C2039: 'uintmax_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''
K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\cstdint(53): error C2873: 'uintmax_t': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"K:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

To configure the compilation, I'm using the following commmand:

```
configure.bat -confirm-license -static -release -prefix "K:\Qt\msvc2015_static" -platform win32-msvc2015 -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-odbc -opensource -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Anyone has a clue of what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

This exact error has been discussed in [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/56453/compiling-qt4-head-with-msvc-2015-cstdint-errors/5) in the Qt forum. It links to an unofficial patch which can be found [here](https://fami.codefreak.ru/mirrors/qt/unofficial_builds/qt4.8.7-msvc2015/02-fix_build_with_msvc2015-45e8f4ee.diff).

For future reference, the contents of the patch are listed below:

```
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/StdHeader.h b/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/StdHeader.h
index 224d400..50adbf6 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/StdHeader.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/StdHeader.h
@@ -123,6 +123,9 @@ extern int _lucene_counter_break; //can set a watch on this
 #endif

 #if !defined(LUCENE_DISABLE_HASHING) && defined(_CL_HAVE_HASH_MAP) && defined(_CL_HAVE_HASH_SET)
+   #if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
+   #define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
+   #endif
    //hashing is all or nothing!
    #include <hash_map>
    #include <hash_set>
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/util/VoidMap.h b/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/util/VoidMap.h
index 1153a01..b37465a 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/util/VoidMap.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/clucene/src/CLucene/util/VoidMap.h
@@ -217,17 +217,28 @@ public:

 //A collection that contains no duplicates
 //does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time
+// MSVC2015: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/110682/3//ALL,unified
 template<typename _kt, typename _vt, 
    typename _Compare,
    typename _KeyDeletor=CL_NS(util)::Deletor::Dummy,
    typename _ValueDeletor=CL_NS(util)::Deletor::Dummy>
 class CLSet:public __CLMap<_kt,_vt,
+#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
+   CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt>,
+#else
    CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt, _Compare>,
+#endif
    _KeyDeletor,_ValueDeletor>
 {
+#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
+   typedef typename CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt> _base;
+   typedef __CLMap<_kt, _vt, CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt>,
+       _KeyDeletor,_ValueDeletor> _this;
+#else
    typedef typename CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt,_Compare> _base;
    typedef __CLMap<_kt, _vt, CL_NS_STD(map)<_kt,_vt, _Compare>,
        _KeyDeletor,_ValueDeletor> _this;
+#endif
 public:
    CLSet ( const bool deleteKey=false, const bool deleteValue=false )
    {
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
index 8e1fdbe..79511ef 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
@@ -172,7 +172,10 @@ namespace JSC {
         void operator delete[](void*);

         void* operator new(size_t, void*);
+// FIXME: strange magic
+#if !(defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
         void operator delete(void*, size_t);
+#endif
     };

     class ArgList {
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
index b1ec09f..11670e2 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
@@ -36,6 +36,7 @@
 #if COMPILER(MSVC)
 // FIXME: why a COMPILER check instead of OS? also, these should be HAVE checks

+#if (_MSC_VER < 1900)
 inline int snprintf(char* buffer, size_t count, const char* format, ...) 
 {
     int result;
@@ -45,6 +46,7 @@ inline int snprintf(char* buffer, size_t count, const char* format, ...)
     va_end(args);
     return result;
 }
+#endif

 #if COMPILER(MSVC7) || OS(WINCE)

diff --git a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
index 7ba487f..790c6a0 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
@@ -170,8 +170,16 @@ namespace WTF {

     // GCC's libstdc++ 20070724 and later supports C++ TR1 type_traits in the std namespace.
     // VC10 (VS2010) and later support C++ TR1 type_traits in the std::tr1 namespace.
+    // VC14 (VS2015) and later support C++11 type_traits in the std namespace, but old TR1 names
+    // have been removed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531344(v=vs.140).aspx
+    // for details.
+#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
+    template<typename T> struct HasTrivialConstructor : public std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T> { };
+    template<typename T> struct HasTrivialDestructor : public std::is_trivially_destructible<T> { };
+#else
     template<typename T> struct HasTrivialConstructor : public std::tr1::has_trivial_constructor<T> { };
     template<typename T> struct HasTrivialDestructor : public std::tr1::has_trivial_destructor<T> { };
+#endif

 #else

diff --git a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/WebKit.pri b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/WebKit.pri
index 9aaaa99..487aad6 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/WebKit.pri
+++ b/src/3rdparty/javascriptcore/WebKit.pri
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ isEmpty(OUTPUT_DIR) {

 DEFINES += BUILDING_QT__=1
 building-libs {
-    win32-msvc*|win32-icc: INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/JavaScriptCore/os-win32
+    win32-msvc200*|win32-msvc2010*|win32-msvc2012*|win32-msvc2013*|win32-icc: INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/JavaScriptCore/os-win32
 } else {
     CONFIG(QTDIR_build) {
         QT += webkit
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
index bb2d2842..627b015 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArgList.h
@@ -174,7 +174,10 @@ namespace JSC {
         void operator delete[](void*);

         void* operator new(size_t, void*);
+// FIXME: strange magic
+#if !(defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
         void operator delete(void*, size_t);
+#endif
     };

     class ArgList {
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
index 371e33b..37e0858 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/StringExtras.h
@@ -37,6 +37,7 @@
 #if COMPILER(MSVC)
 // FIXME: why a COMPILER check instead of OS? also, these should be HAVE checks

+#if (_MSC_VER < 1900)
 inline int snprintf(char* buffer, size_t count, const char* format, ...) 
 {
     int result;
@@ -52,6 +53,7 @@ inline int snprintf(char* buffer, size_t count, const char* format, ...)

     return result;
 }
+#endif

 inline double wtf_vsnprintf(char* buffer, size_t count, const char* format, va_list args)
 {
diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
index 44103cd..7b09980 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h
@@ -183,8 +183,16 @@ namespace WTF {

     // GCC's libstdc++ 20070724 and later supports C++ TR1 type_traits in the std namespace.
     // VC10 (VS2010) and later support C++ TR1 type_traits in the std::tr1 namespace.
+    // VC14 (VS2015) and later support C++11 type_traits in the std namespace, but old TR1 names
+    // have been removed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb531344(v=vs.140).aspx
+    // for details.
+#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900))
+    template<typename T> struct HasTrivialConstructor : public std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T> { };
+    template<typename T> struct HasTrivialDestructor : public std::is_trivially_destructible<T> { };
+#else
     template<typename T> struct HasTrivialConstructor : public std::tr1::has_trivial_constructor<T> { };
     template<typename T> struct HasTrivialDestructor : public std::tr1::has_trivial_destructor<T> { };
+#endif

 #else

diff --git a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pri b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pri
index 01f88a4..b607444 100644
--- a/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pri
+++ b/src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/WebKit.pri
@@ -38,7 +38,7 @@ DEPENDPATH += $$OUT_PWD

 DEFINES += BUILDING_QT__=1
 building-libs {
-    win32-msvc*|win32-icc: INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/JavaScriptCore/os-win32
+    win32-msvc200*|win32-msvc2010*|win32-msvc2012*|win32-msvc2013*|win32-icc: INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/JavaScriptCore/os-win32
 } else {
     CONFIG(QTDIR_build) {
         QT += webkit
```

Comment: The patch is unterminated (missing at least closingbrackets), do you still have the full version ?

Comment: @LaurentCrivello I took the patch from the link as referenced in the answer. I also applied the changes manually as I wanted to see them in effect individually and that worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

@Bowdzone thanks. this patch worked like a charm for building qt4.8.7

I also needed to append "$(QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2015" after msvc2013 option in C:\repo\qt\4.8.7\qmake\Makefile.win32( line 27), to get the configure command to work - as noted in [building qt for msvc2015 guide lines](https://forum.qt.io/topic/59923/building-qt-with-visual-studio-2015-guide-lines)

BTW I had to build qt4.8.7 as a dependency for 3dslicer OSS package.

p.s I dont have enough points to add-a-comment. This is a validation that the patch worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command prompt as administrator, I did it and worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because you probably have a very long path for location of source codes. So try to shorten the path for location of codes. For example put them in a short folder name in root of a drive.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14862127/2385309

Comment: No, the path of the source code is K:\Qt\Qt5.

Also, it is not the same problem as the thread you attached, I'm not having a "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error

Comment: Can you copy paste your PATH and VISUALDIR environment variables. Also you already have other errors in your code, `symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration` also try to fix those

Comment: Also, do you use a custom -arch instruction in build command?

Comment: Stuff like this always happen to everyone :)